# Seaborn heatmap throwing unexpected error

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to execute following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
year = range(1949,1961)
month = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
passengers = pd.Series(np.random.randint(100, 1000, len(year)*len(month)), name='passengers')
years = pd.Series(year * len(month), name='years')
months = pd.Series(month * len(year), name='months').sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.DataFrame([years, months, passengers]).T
df_flight = df.pivot(index="months", columns="years", values="passengers")
sns.heatmap(df_flight, annot=True, fmt="d", linewidths=.5)
```

It was throwing unexpected error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Kindly explain what is error in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You need convert values to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), because `strings`:

```
sns.heatmap(df_flight.astype(int), annot=True, fmt="d", linewidths=.5)
```

---

Problem is if use `DataFrame` constructor this way and values at least one column are `string`s, then it convert all values to `strings` too:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([years, months, passengers]).T

print (df.dtypes)
years         object
months        object
passengers    object
```

Solution is use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) or `DataFrame` constructor with `dict`s:

```
df = pd.concat([years, months, passengers], axis=1)

print (df.dtypes)
years          int64
months        object
passengers     int32
dtype: object

...

sns.heatmap(df_flight, annot=True, fmt="d", linewidths=.5)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'years':years, 'months':months, 'passengers':passengers})

print (df.dtypes)
months        object
passengers     int32
years          int64
dtype: object

...

sns.heatmap(df_flight, annot=True, fmt="d", linewidths=.5)
```

[image: graph]